# "Found staticlib instead of rlib or dylib" when compiling using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, rust, rust-crates

I'm using the image crate and Visual Studio with Rust plugin. The code is like this:

```
extern crate image;
```

When I use the command line `cargo build`, everything was fine. With the Visual Studio build I get

```
src\main.rs(4,1): error : found staticlib `image` instead of rlib or dylib
help: please recompile this crate using --crate-type lib
```

How can I use the crate in Visual Studio?

Comment: Troubleshooting: try passing the verbose flag to cargo on both the command line and in VS's invocation, and see what differences there are between the outputs.

Comment: I found the answer at https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/VisualRust/issues the Visual Rust plugin does not support cargo now,it just run the rustc when you compile